# Audio analysis with python + octave

Tags: python, audio, octave

i want to analysis audio files with Python and Octave. Acutally i am getting an error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/AudioTools/ShutterTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    (peaks, indexes) = octave.findpeaks(np.array(test), 'DoubleSided')
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

my Code is:

```
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from scipy.io import wavfile
    from oct2py import octave
    samplerate, data = wavfile.read("TestWav.wav")

    cb = np.array(data, dtype=np.int16)

    test =[d[0] for d in cb]
    octave.eval("pkg load signal")
    (peaks, indexes) = octave.findpeaks(np.array(test), 'DoubleSided')
    plt.plot(peaks)
    plt.show()
```

Can someone give an advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version 4.0.0 of oct2py (see release notes [here](https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py/blob/9504dbfe95995f77d227ffb68395220cd4012d66/HISTORY.rst#400-2017-03-07)), it is necessary to provide an `nout` argument when requiring more outputs.

So in your case you have to do:

```
(peaks, indexes) = octave.findpeaks(np.array(test), 'DoubleSided', nout=2)
```

Comment: @droidfish I understand your question is quite old and I hope you already figured this out. I run into the same problems, saw your question while looking for solution, so when I finally found an answer, I thought I might share it for others too.